# Serve html, CSS and JS file in ASP.NET which are outside of MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following folder structure which is located on D partition and it is outside of MVC application:

```
D:\item\html_file.html
D:\item\content\style.css
D:\item\js\site.js
```

the `html_file.html` has reference to js and css like:

`<link href="content/style.css" ... />`

`<script src='js/site.js'>`

And in MVC action I have something like:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetItem(string id)
  {
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)) {
        throw new HttpException((int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "The id doesn't exist");
     }

     // get/verify user's rights and permissions

     try {
        string file = @"D:\item\html_file.html";
        return File(file, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file));
     } catch (Exception e) {
        // return 404
     }
  }
```

But that no CSS and JS files were loaded (it gave me 404, trying to access `www.blabla.com/myCtrl/getitem/content/style.css`).

My question: how to load those css and js which are outside of MVC application ?

Thanks

Comment: www.blabla.com/content/style.css try this

Comment: I said that HTML, CSS and JS it's outside of MVC application and they cannot be accessed by URL. Only served from my controller's action.

Comment: www.blabla.com/myCtrl/getitem/content/style.css there is no physical file available at this location. How could you access then?

Comment: I found the solution, I have to register in IIS a virtual directory for `D:\item\`

Answer (score 0):

You assume that your server's current position is inside the *item* folder:

```
<link href="content/style.css" ... />

<script src='js/site.js'>
```

However, it might be not the case. If you add a slash to the paths

```
<link href="/content/style.css" ... />

<script src='/js/site.js'>
```

then they will be searched inside the root folder of your application. If the item folder happens to be that, then this will solve your problem. If not, then you will need to add a prefix to this, containing their path starting from the root, just remember to start the paths with slash.

Comment: I said that HTML, CSS and JS it's outside of MVC application and they cannot be accessed by URL. Only served from my controller's action.